# Azure mobile services - how to develop in production with a version already deployed?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I've been ramping up on Azure Mobile Services over the past week.  There are definitely some PROs and CONs in using them over a standard Azure Web Site where I can write APIs that hit SQL DB, etc.

One of the biggest negatives I see is developing the server side code and DB structures ON THE SERVER.  I've watched lots of videos from launch and beyond, read lots of blog posts about tips and tricks around WAMS, but nobody seems to talk about the downside of developing the code (server scripts) and database structures on the server, at your live URL.

This is all great for developing the first version of your mobile app and associated mobile services.  But once it's all deployed, how do you ever build version 2?  Real apps hitting real APIs and data, but now I want to develop/change/play with the server scripts and database schema?

With Azure Web Sites, I can develop locally and only publish code and DB changes to the server on my schedule.

Have any of you seen or heard of the "v2 development story" around Azure Mobile Services?

Only thing I can think of would be to create another set of tables and APIs around them, most likely "virtual tables" that allow me to write APIs against the original set of data.  Seems like a huge hassle, since the client code would now have to know about the original set of tables and the new set of tables... that's only for v2...

Thanks for any thoughts / insight.

Comment: What solution you end up using?

Answer (score 3):

You should have two services, one dev and one production and use scripts to promote your code from dev to production (pretty similar to how most workflows go, in moving from a test setup to a production one).

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2013/3-511

Comment: Ahh - forgot that each mobile service gets its own schema in the DB.  Couldn't figure out how I was going to have 2 services with same table, hitting the same DB (FREE single DB to start out).  I wonder why they (you? ;)) don't offer a VIP switch between staging and production like web roles do?  Maybe (hopefully) that's in the plans.  Thanks for the help.